# DB Design for 2 tables where we want to link their primary keys

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, paging

There are two tables **feedback** and **action** both tables have primary key *feedback_Id* and *action_Id* respectively.

We have frontend pages for Action where for a given action we can view the feedback(using the feedback_Id) and on Feedback frontend page we can view the Action related to it.

so now i decided to link these two table for that i have created another table **LinkActionFeedback** which have two foreign fields which refer to  **feedback.feedback_Id** and **action.action_Id**.

We are fetching actions using pagination. At this time, we also need the feedback_Id for each action. one way to retrieve feedback_Id is to  perform join operation with **LinkActionFeedback** table.

Is there any other option for retrieving feedback_Id related to the actions while fetching actions using pagination by using a different DB design. I have a feeling that the Join operation might be expensive because in a single pagination call we retrieve 30 actions.

Comment: as explained in the question I created a LinkActionFeedback table

Comment: Is relationship between Action and Feedback many-to-many? or just one-to-many? you say (Feedback ... can view the Action related to it)

Comment: Its one-to-one relationship, Feedback can view the action related to it and action  can view the Feedback related to it

Comment: You are not clear. If there is a 1:1 relationship on actions:feedback then edit that into your question. Or is it 1or0:1or0? Also give other constraints on the data. Give DDL & example data & queries--give a [mcve]. How is LinkActionFeedback any different than select aid, fid from action or select aid, fid from feedback? According to your question & comments they are the same and there is no *point* to joining LinkActionFeedback with either original table because that would just return the original table. Explain what pagination has to do with this because so far it doesn't and you haven't.